# A question about the uniqueness in Hilbert's Nullstellensatz

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field. One of the formulations of Hilbert's weak Nullstellensatz is that each maximal ideal in $k[x_1, \dots , x_n]$ has the form $\langle x_1 -a_1 , \dots , x_n - a_n\rangle $, where $a = (a_1 , \dots , a_n)$ is a point in affine space $k^n$. Is the point $a$ unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assume $b = (b_1,\dots,b_n)$ is another point like $a$ then:
$$\langle x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n\rangle=\langle x_1-b_1,\dots,x_n-b_n\rangle .$$
So $x_1 -b_1 = \sum f_i (x_i-a_i) \ \ , \ \exists f_i \in k[x] .$
Can you explain why this is not possible if $b_1 \not= a_1$?

Comment: The $f_i \in k[x]$ or $f_i \in k[x_1, \cdots x_n]$

Comment: im sorry ∈[1,⋯]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!